# What's the point of jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(someData));

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Came across this snippet

```
var someDataJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(someData));
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the inner "method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string"; then the outer method "Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript value" per [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

If you start with a JS value & end up with a JS value, is this a pointless operation?

Comment: There's no point unless there's some point in the example you're looking at. Where did you come across that snippet? Is this something that Proconsul Claudius Marcus put you up to?

Comment: My personal favorite solution for object cloning by value is the [`history.replaceState` structured clone hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10916838/1541563).

Comment: @Pointy the code isn't open source; but now that I know it's a object copy hack, things make more sense ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually that is a trick used to get a **by-value copy** of an object in javascript. (Since all objects are passed by reference). You can find a more in-depth answer on how to accomplish this, if you're curious, in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869248/1741244)

Comment: This is true but it should be noted that unless one knows that the objects involved are pretty small, it's a sub-optimal way to make a copy.

Comment: Thanks for linking that post; I didn't actually know copying JS objects could be that complex?!

Answer (score 2):

If `someDataJSON` is a flat JSON object, this way you get a **copy of that object**. Since, there is no direct method to copy a javascript object "by value" [and not "by reference"], this trick can be used.

```
var copyJSONObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSONObj))
```

*So, there is some point after all.*